# How does the definition of ratios in book 5 of the Elements allow for dealing with the ratio of incommensurable numbers

Tags: ratio

Definition in Book 5 of the Elements

"Magnitudes are said to be in the same ratio, the first to the second and the third to the fourth, when, if any equimultiples whatever are taken of the first and third, and any equimultiples whatever of the second and fourth, the former equimultiples alike exceed, are alike equal to, or alike fall short of, the latter equimultiples respectively taken in corresponding order"

How does this new definition allow for dealing with the ratio of incommensurable numbers and why was the old method inadequate?

Comment: See [Euclid's *Elements*, Book V: Background on ratio and proportion](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookV/bookV.html) exactly because the original "expectation": that the ratio of two magnitudes whatever can always be expressed as a number (a natural one), was proven to be incorrect.